# How do I change my css dropdown to change sizes according to the size of the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
    .dropdown select {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
    
      color: blue;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: underline;
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 1.75;
    
      display:inline-block;

      background-color: #ffffff;
      background-image: none;
      border-style: none;
    
      background: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") no-repeat right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
          <span class="header"> COMPARE </span>
          <span class="dropdown">
               <select class="select_box" id="opts">
                 <p></p>
                 <option value="default">Select a dataset</option>
                 <option value="population">POPULATION</option>
                 <option value="popdensityperacre">POPULATION DENSITY</option>
                 <option value="percapitaincome">INCOME</option>
                    <option value="percentnonwhite">RACIAL DIVERSITY</option>
                    <option value="percentinpoverty">POVERTY</option>
                    <option value="medianhomevalue">HOME VALUE</option>
                    <option value="unemploymentrate">UNEMPLOYMENT</option>
                    <option value="percapitacriminalarrests">CRIME</option>
                    <option value="percapitaencampments">HOMELESSNESS</option>
                    <option value="medianhoursofsummerfog">FOG</option>
                    <option value="percentinliquefaction">LIQUEFACTION</option>
                </select>
          </span>
          <span class="header"> BY NEIGHBORHOOD </span>
      </div>
```

How do I get it so the box changes sizes depending on which selection is chosen? I thought it might work if I make it an `inline-block` and then set width to 100%.

The reason I'd like the box-size to change is that I'd like the dropdown arrow to be right next to the text, instead of staying in a fixed location.

Comment: By default, a `select` element will try to be the width of the widest option in the list. If you want to change this, you'll need javascript for that.

Comment: 100% should work, what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

So if I got it right, the solution would be to just add some `:hover` css to a class.
Look at this example on w3school:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

I clicked on "Try it yourself" and altered the code as I believe you want to.
With the following css code you can alter the div option as you want when you hover it.

```
.select-items div:hover {   
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 50px; 
}
```

Hope it helped.

Explore the example for more things, they have css for all the parts of a selection menu.